# not able to fetch text data from web url using javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I need to extract text data from web url (http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf)

I used two node_module.

**1) crawler-Request**

```
  it('Read Pdf Data using crawler',function(){
        const crawler = require('crawler-request');
        function response_text_size(response){
            response["size"] = response.text.length;
            return response;
        }
        crawler("http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf",response_text_size).then(function(response){
            // handle response

            console.log("Reponse =" + response.size);
        });

    });
```

What happen for this it will not print anything on console.

**2) pfd2json/pdfparser**

```
it('Read Data from url',function(){
        var request = require('request');
        var pdf = require('pfd2json/pdfparser');
        var fs = require('fs');
        var pdfUrl = "http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf";
        let databuffer = fs.readFileSync(pdfUrl);
        pdf(databuffer).then(function(data){
            var arr:Array<String> = data.text;
            var n = arr.includes('Thursday 02 May');
            console.log("Print Array " + n);
        });

    });
```

> - Failed: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf'

I am able to access data from local path but not able to extract it from url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using the `fs` module (File System) to read a file on a distant server.

You also mistyped the `pdf2json` module, which should give you an error ?

You did require the `request` module. This module will make it possible to access that distant file. Here's one way to do this :

```
it('Read Data from url', function () {
    var request = require('request');
    var PDFParser = require('pdf2json');

    var pdfUrl = 'http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf';

    var pdfParser = new PDFParser(this, 1);

    // executed if the parser fails for any reason
    pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => console.error(errData.parserError));
    // executed when the parser finished
    pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => console.log(pdfParser.getRawTextContent()));

    // request to get the pdf's file content then call the pdf parser on the retrieved buffer
    request({ url: pdfUrl, encoding: null }, (error, response, body) => pdfParser.parseBuffer(body));
});
```

This will make it possible to load the distant .pdf file in your program.

I'd recommend looking at the [`pdf2json` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2json) if you want to do more. This will simply output the textual content of the .pdf file when the parser has completed reading data.

Comment: how can i get all the text from that pdf ?

Comment: @sailxor what i need to do i need all text from that pdf in console.log how can i print that ?

Comment: @dhrusoni I've updated my answer. This will simply log the pdf's file content in the console. You should look at the documentation if you want to do more with this module :)

Comment: it's not printing anything on console.log it just passed all the testcase.

Comment: i edited my code i just put console.log at the last line and it working like charm...